# angular unable to import Stripe to component

Tags: angular, stripe-payments

i want to create a stripe checkout in angular. The logic is the same as the example from stripe but i cannot import Stripe in my component class:

```
import {Stripe} from '@stripe/stripe-js';
```

Here is my usecase:

```
  stripe = Stripe("mytoken");
```

Webstorm says:

> 'Stripe' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.

So i think the import is wrong but i actually dont know how to use the script from html. The example from stripe is using this class directly in a script tag:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
// Create an instance of the Stripe object with your publishable API key
var stripe = Stripe("pk_test_51HaOuLKpHoRFb17FLbnrAQYRee73V3Xc3PzYkOcFmmC9OUbqgY8jW2fDLtNeWOEJKwOfYg9NTKtW1JfDIW2foeel00IsfFQfQW");
var checkoutButton = document.getElementById("checkout-button");

checkoutButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
  fetch("/create-session", {
    method: "POST",
  })
    .then(function (response) {
      return response.json();
    })
    .then(function (session) {
      return stripe.redirectToCheckout({ sessionId: session.id });
    })
    .then(function (result) {
      // If redirectToCheckout fails due to a browser or network
      // error, you should display the localized error message to your
      // customer using error.message.
      if (result.error) {
        alert(result.error.message);
      }
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.error("Error:", error);
    });
});
```

Comment: Looking at the [docs](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-js#usage) you're not instantiating it correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd use `Stripe('pk_test_123')` to initialize if you were [including Stripe.js directly](https://stripe.com/docs/js/including).

Using `@stripe/stripe-js` (a wrapper for loading the underlying `stripe.js` resource) you should follow the [Usage docs](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-js#usage) to initialize with `loadStripe` instead:

```
import {loadStripe} from '@stripe/stripe-js';

const stripe = await loadStripe('pk_test_123');
```